# Unable to show warning or errors with explicitApiWarning()

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

I'm planning to use explicitApiWarning for my library that is made with kotlin.
The problem is that I've set the following script inside build.gradle file. Unfortunately it doesn't show any warnings or errors. Could it be that the following tag should be placed in a specific spot(Such as within android {})? Or will there be some specific setups necessary? According to the document, it seems simple but I cannot have it work. Aside from that I wanted to know if its possible to set both explicitApiWarning and explicitApi together? Some tips or examples will be helpful. Thank you.

```
kotlin {
  explicitApiWarning()
}
```

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#explicit-api-mode-for-library-authors

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

        
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 29
            buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
        
            defaultConfig {
                minSdkVersion 24
                targetSdkVersion 29
                versionName "1.0"
        
                testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            }
        
      buildTypes {
        release {
          minifyEnabled false
        }
      }
    
      lintOptions {
        abortOnError true
      }
  }
        kotlin {
                explicitApiWarning()
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For android library modules, set explicit api as follows:

```
android {
  kotlinOptions {
    freeCompilerArgs += '-Xexplicit-api=warning'
  }
}
```

Comment: Then in what scenario will kotlin { explicitApiWarning() } be used ? 
Does it mean if I have apply plugin: 'com.android.library', I should use the script that you mentioned?

Comment: kotlin { explicitApiWarning() } works for java/kotlin modules. Seems there is a bug in kotlin that stops it working for android modules. For android modules, set the explcit api using the freeCompilerArgs as shown above.

Comment: Thank you, I will use your recommendation. I want to know if I can set the warning & explict at the time. Where did you get  the info regarding the bug in kotlin that doesn't work in android modules? Some links will be so helpful! But thank you for the answer above.